# one-wire over bit banging vs. one wire over usart

Tags: stm32, usart, 1wire

I want to use a sensor with one-wire protocol, the matter is which way of using this protocol is optimized and more rational? over usart or using bit banging?

if it is important I'm using am2305 and stm32fxx microcontrollers.

Comment: I never know the USARTs on microcontrollers came ready to support any one-wire protocol.

Comment: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/214

take a look at this link,it's common but which one is technical is the matter!  @CortAmmon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm prefer to use USART+DMA with one buffer for transmit and receive. And I think this choice depends on your skill and requierements of your project.

There many ways to implement one-wire protocol.

- exti interrupts + timer base mode
- timer input capture + dma
- usart interrupts
- usart (err interrupts only) + dma

All of them have thier advantages and disadvantages:

- busy or free pins
- busy or free periferals (tim, usart)
- busy or free dma channels
- lower or higher frequency of interrupts in programm
- easy or hard for implement it

I have different projects where work first and last methods listed above.

**You must know which method is preferred for you and your project.**

Comment: thanks, Is there any difference in speed of receiving data ? 
Can we say that bit banging is not principled and we shouldn't use it in industrial designs? @imbearr

Comment: @SadraNaddaf, speed more depends on pull up resistance value. For industrial designs you should use stable solution and no more over.